# Failed to create session factory with embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, junit5, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm encountering a jakarta.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory error when attempting to access a test embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server in Spring Boot. Here's my setup:

> jakarta.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory

ConnectionFactory Bean:

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
    }
```

Test code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JmsConfig.class, JmsListenerTest.TestConfig.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JmsListenerTest {

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
            return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @SpyBean
    private NotifierMessageListener listener;

    @Test
    public void receive()  {

        final var message = new NacqMessage("s2", "receive test");
        jmsTemplate.send(NotifierMessageListener.MAILBOX_JSON, s -> s.createObjectMessage(message)); //throws Failed to create session factory

      ...
    }
}
```

Relevant gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jms'
testImplementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jakarta-server:2.32.0' //not sure if needed.
```

The issue arises only with the embedded server, whereas using a non-embedded server works fine. I've referred to the official documentation but haven't found sufficient guidance on configuring the embedded server correctly. What additional configuration might be needed in this scenario?

Official Documentation Reference: Using ActiveMQConnectionFactory on Artemis Page

Answer (score 1):

The URL `vm://localhost` is not valid. The in-vm connector must reference the **ID** where the server is listening. You should almost certainly using `vm://0` instead.

Of course, this assumes that an embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis is actually being started for your test and said instance has an in-vm `acceptor` listening on `vm://0`.

Comment: Still the same error. Where do I define/create those IDs?

Comment: You'd need to look at the configuration of the embedded broker. Are you sure one is being created and started?

Comment: This : `spring.artemis.mode=embedded` at application.properties ? Still don't work.

Comment: I'm not a Spring expert so I can't say how you need to configure Spring so that it starts an embedded broker for your test. However, if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I bet I (or someone else) could work out what's gone wrong.